# Can't pass variable from one file to another using $GLOBALS array

Tags: php

I'm studing php and I've read this (important words are bold):

> Superglobals — Superglobals are built-in variables that are **always**
>   available in **all scopes**
>   These superglobal variables are:

- $GLOBALS
- $_SERVER
- .........

In `file1.php` I do:

```
$GLOBALS["ZZZ"] = 555;
```

Then I have to send `file2.php` to client, so here, in `file1.php` I do:

```
header("Location: /file2.php");
```

Now I want to retrive my global variable from the global array in `file2.php`. I do:

```
echo "My global = ".$GLOBALS["ZZZ"].";";
```

And I get emptyness...
What do I do wrong? Is $GLOBALS really global or it is new after redirection? Thank you in advance.

Comment: $GLOBALS is set per request afaik, you maybe want to use sessions? Or whatever other persistent storage.

Comment: If you want something to exist across requests, you need to save it somewhere, maybe `$_SESSION`

Comment: Its only GLOBAL for the life time of the execution of a Single script. You should look at using the SESSION

Comment: I've already used sessions and succeeded, but this message confuses me:
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at ......

Comment: Every new request in PHP starts from scratch. What that quote means it that you can access those variables in any scope (functions, classes etc), but they will still only exist for that specific request. When you redirect the user, then PHP will start from scratch again.

Comment: For your session_start warning see -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php

Comment: Ok guys, I've got it! Thanks! Wrong (unclear) documentation here:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php
NOT ALWAYS, but only before next request.

Comment: No, the documentation is correct. The `description` part is more concise `Several predefined variables in PHP are "superglobals", which means they are available in all scopes throughout a script. There is no need to do global $variable; to access them within functions or methods.` I.e. available in all your script's scopes, so you can use it anywhere in code and it will be available.

Comment: I was confused by word "always". I tried to find something like window.localStorage, something that is really accessible from anywhere in any time. 
Now using SESSION blocks my code where I use echo. Backend isn't easy :-)

Comment: PS: done my taks with session_start(); Thank the community